# Error when executing TwitterSearch in Python

Tags: python

I am currently attempting to use TwitterSearch (https://github.com/ckoepp/TwitterSearch) to import tweets into a csv for analysis. However, I am getting the following error message when executing the python script:

```
from .TwitterSearchException import TwitterSearchException
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package
```

Here is the code:

```
from TwitterSearch import *
from TwitterSearchException import *
import csv

def get_tweets(query, max_tweets):
    query = raw_input ("Search for:")
    max_tweets = 2000
    # takes a search term (query) and a max number of tweets to find
    # gets content from twitter and writes it to a csv bearing the name of your query

    i = 0
    search = query

    with open(search+'.csv', 'wb') as outf:
        writer = csv.writer(outf)
        writer.writerow(['user','time','tweet','latitude','longitude'])
        try:
            tso = TwitterSearchOrder()
            tso.set_keywords([search])
            tso.set_language('en') # English tweets only

            ts = TwitterSearch(
                consumer_key = '',
                consumer_secret = '',
                access_token = '',
                access_token_secret = ''
            )

            for tweet in ts.search_tweets_iterable(tso):
                lat = None
                long = None
                time = tweet['created_at'] # UTC time when Tweet was created.
                user = tweet['user']['screen_name']
                tweet_text = tweet['text'].strip().encode('ascii', 'ignore')
                tweet_text = ''.join(tweet_text.splitlines())
                print i,time,
                if tweet['geo'] != None and tweet['geo']['coordinates'][0] != 0.0: # avoiding bad values
                    lat = tweet['geo']['coordinates'][0]
                    long = tweet['geo']['coordinates'][1]
                    print('@%s: %s' % (user, tweet_text)), lat, long
                else:
                    print('@%s: %s' % (user, tweet_text))

                writer.writerow([user, time, tweet_text, lat, long])
                i += 1
                if i > max:
                    return()

        except TwitterSearchException as e:
            print(e)
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try a more specific import for the `TwitterSearchException` line, instead of the `*`.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
from TwitterSearch.TwitterSearchException import TwitterSearchException
```

`TwitterSearchException` is not a python package, `TwitterSearch` is.